# Get numbers that does not exist in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have 2 integers.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3;
```

This is my code as of now, I want to do it vice versa, which is to get the integer that does not exist.
Instead of getting the existing numbers which are 1,2,3. I would like to execute a command on the numbers  that does not exist (4 & 5).

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $a; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $b; $y++) {
        if ($x == $y)
        {
            echo $y." = Exist Do some commands here<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem by the most laborious way? You don't need two loops to find existing/non-existing numbers.

Comment: Hi @Flocke, im trying to use this two loops because I have to delete these IDs in mysql which is example: 4,5 (the ones that does not exist). Can you suggest another way for me to just show the missing numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
<?php
$a = 3;
$b = 5;

$arrNotExists = [];

for ($i = $a + 1; $i <= $b; $i++) {
    $arrNotExists[] = $i;
}

var_dump($arrNotExists);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/bOSsH8

Another solution using two arrays with [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
<?php
$a = 3;
$b = 5;

$arrA = [];
$arrB = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $a; $i++) {
    $arrA[] = $i;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $b; $i++) {
    $arrB[] = $i;
}

$arrNotExists = array_diff($arrB, $arrA);

var_dump($arrNotExists);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/OtSwnN

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what im looking for! :D

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question as a solution to it please try executing following code snippet

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3;
$temp=array();
$result=array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= $a; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $b; $y++) {
         $temp[]=$y;

    }
 if(in_array($x,$temp)==false)
        {
           $result[]=$x;
        }
}
```

Also please try executing another alternative solution

```
$a1 = range(1, $a);
$a2 = range(1, $b);
$result = array_diff($a1, $a2);
```